# Printing Deck List in Python Using OOP?

Tags: python

can someone please let me know how I can print out the list of cards in the deck using OOP? I'm currently taking a class and trying to learn Python 2.

I tried assigning d = Deck() and then print d.cards but it only returns the memory location in a list for all 52 cards.

What am I missing?

```
 import random

 rank = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'Jack','Queen','King','Ace']
 suit = ['Diamonds','Clubs','Hearts','Spade']

 class Card(object):
    def __init__(self,rank,suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rank) + ' of ' + str(self.suit)

    def grab_suit(self):
        return self.suit

    def grab_rank(self):
        return self.rank

    def draw(self):
        print (self.suit + self.rank)

class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []    
        for i in rank:
            for j in suit:
                self.cards.append(Card(i,j))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cards()
```

Answer (score 2):

In `Deck.__str__`, you want to get a list of the string representations of the `Card`s:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str([str(card) for card in self.cards])
```

The reason you need to do this is that when Python prints a list, it formats the contents by their `__repr__`, not their `__str__`. We want the string representations, so we generate the list of strings ourselves by explicitly calling `str`, which will end up calling `Card.__str__()`.

Another thing to note: writing getters for attributes when you aren't executing other code is pointless. I would recommend getting rid of `Card.grab_suit()` and `Card.grab_rank()`.  Just do `card.suit` and `card.rank`.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the def__str__(self) portion and tried printing d. However I got an error:


TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-fecf9a1ec6f3> in <module>()
----> 1 print d

TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type list)

Can you please explain why?

Comment: @paulnsn Just edited in the fix - the return value of `__str__` needs to be a string, so I wrapped the list in another `str` call.

Answer (score 0):

When did:

```
print(d.cards)
```

The `print` function only called the list object's `__str__` method. If you want each elements `__str__` method called, you'll have to do it explicitly:

```
print([str(card) for card in d.cards])
```